# Getting "cannot unpack non-iterable Particle object" while using SymPy mechanics module

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am working to generate an animation of a triple pendulum system using the SymPy mechanics module. During the build phase of the model using Kane's method, the particles list starts out as an empty list, and is then appended with the particle calculations. Upon calling the particle list in the kanes_equations I am met with the "cannot unpack non-iterable Particle object", although the forces list goes through the same procedure and works without throwing an error.

```
def integrate_pendulum(n, times,
                       initial_positions=135,
                       initial_velocities=0,
                       lengths=None, masses=1):
    """Integrate a multi-pendulum with `n` sections"""
    #-------------------------------------------------
    # Step 1: construct the pendulum model
    
    # Generalized coordinates and velocities
    # (in this case, angular positions & velocities of each mass) 
    q = mechanics.dynamicsymbols('q:{0}'.format(n))
    u = mechanics.dynamicsymbols('u:{0}'.format(n))

    # mass and length
    m = symbols('m:{0}'.format(n))
    l = symbols('l:{0}'.format(n))

    # gravity and time symbols
    g, t = symbols('g,t')
    
    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Step 2: build the model using Kane's Method

    # Create pivot point reference frame
    A = mechanics.ReferenceFrame('A')
    P = mechanics.Point('P')
    P.set_vel(A, 0)

    # lists to hold particles, forces, and kinetic ODEs
    # for each pendulum in the chain
    particles = []
    forces = []
    kinetic_odes = []

    for i in range(n):
        # Create a reference frame following the i^th mass
        Ai = A.orientnew('A' + str(i), 'Axis', [q[i], A.z])
        Ai.set_ang_vel(A, u[i] * A.z)

        # Create a point in this reference frame
        Pi = P.locatenew('P' + str(i), l[i] * Ai.x)
        Pi.v2pt_theory(P, A, Ai)

        # Create a new particle of mass m[i] at this point
        # Pai = mechanics.Particle('Pa' + str(i), Pi, m[i])
        Pai = mechanics.Particle('Pa' + str(i), Pi, m[i])
        particles.append(Pai)

        # Set forces & compute kinematic ODE
        forces.append((Pi, m[i] * g * A.x))
        kinetic_odes.append(q[i].diff(t) - u[i])

        P = Pi

    # Generate equations of motion
    KM = mechanics.KanesMethod(A, q_ind=q, u_ind=u,
                               kd_eqs=kinetic_odes)
    fr, fr_star = KM.kanes_equations(forces, particles)
    
    #-----------------------------------------------------
    # Step 3: numerically evaluate equations and integrate

    # initial positions and velocities – assumed to be given in degrees
    y0 = np.deg2rad(np.concatenate([np.broadcast_to(initial_positions, n),
                                    np.broadcast_to(initial_velocities, n)]))
        
    # lengths and masses
    if lengths is None:
        lengths = np.ones(n) / n
    lengths = np.broadcast_to(lengths, n)
    masses = np.broadcast_to(masses, n)

    # Fixed parameters: gravitational constant, lengths, and masses
    parameters = [g] + list(l) + list(m)
    parameter_vals = [9.81] + list(lengths) + list(masses)

    # define symbols for unknown parameters
    unknowns = [Dummy() for i in q + u]
    unknown_dict = dict(zip(q + u, unknowns))
    kds = KM.kindiffdict()

    # substitute unknown symbols for qdot terms
    mm_sym = KM.mass_matrix_full.subs(kds).subs(unknown_dict)
    fo_sym = KM.forcing_full.subs(kds).subs(unknown_dict)

    # create functions for numerical calculation 
    mm_func = lambdify(unknowns + parameters, mm_sym)
    fo_func = lambdify(unknowns + parameters, fo_sym)

    # function which computes the derivatives of parameters
    def gradient(y, t, args):
        vals = np.concatenate((y, args))
        sol = np.linalg.solve(mm_func(*vals), fo_func(*vals))
        return np.array(sol).T[0]

    # ODE integration
    return odeint(gradient, y0, times, args=(parameter_vals,))
```

I am running the following code to attempt at generating a plot showing the pendulums motion history

```
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
p = integrate_pendulum(n=3, times=t)
x, y = get_xy_coords(p)
plt.plot(x, y);
```

I expected to see a plot similar to the following:
[triple pendulum motion history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FUzp.png)

But it seems the code is unable to unpack the Particle function in the current form it is being saved as. I am not too familiar with this code as it is not mine and I am looking to modify it for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

kanes_equations() had a deprecation some years back. The API is now:

fr, frstar = kane.kanes_equations(particles, forces)

as opposed to the (forces, particles) seen in the code in the original post.